# Return all values with matching key value pair

Tags: php

Given this:

```
        $array1 = array(
            array(
                'orderno' => 2,
            ),
            array(
                'orderno' => 2,
            ),,
            array(
                'orderno' => 1                      
            ),
        );
```

How do i get all the arrays with a orderno = 2 leaving out the orderno = 1, I know you could do this via a foreach but I'd like to know if it could be done using a native php method instead of a foreach... 
Similar to:

```
array_search($cmsvalue['custnum'], array_column($custcsvarray, 'custnum'));
```

but returning all the values not just the first...

Comment: `foreach` *is* native PHP.

Comment: That is a very very very good point... I suppose my question is how to do it without a foreach.... I'm going to be running this inside a foreach allready and the array I'm querying is huge. I need a way to get straight to the point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `foreach` is not native enough, you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). The function accepts a callback that is applied to each item. The result is an array that returns all items for which the callback didn't return false.

```
$array2 = array_filter($array1, function($item) {
  return $item['orderno'] == 2;
});
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was lookng for :D thank you.. I was stuck in array_intersect for some reason but hey php is never my friend..

Comment: heheheh there was a dig in ther with foreach not being native enough wasn't there!

Comment: array filter is exactly what i wanted weird usign callbacks in php it's like it's a proper language :D

Comment: PHP also excepts strings with function names. That was the original definition of 'callable'. Later it also supported strings with names of static method of classes and arrays with an object instance and method name. The more recent versions support actual inline functions. Eventually they'll get there. ;-)

Comment: One day in a galaxy far far away? :P

Comment: damn does array_filter create scope? as in do I have acces to values outside of it?

Comment: found it I need to use "use"